# How to get AutoHotkey to capture Right Windows Key

Tags: autohotkey, windows-key

I have some AutoHotKey scripts that use or override some of the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>char</kbd> combinations.  On my laptop or work keyboard, where I only have 1 windows key, these work fine.  On my home desktop, my keyboard has a Right Windows key, which does not respond the same.  On the AHK site I can see that for the windows keys, there are special characters for that key because of this difference, however I can't figure out how to make it grab my combos.  For example, I have this one to override the default action with OneNote:

```
#n::Send #N
```

When I do that with the right windows key, it does nothing.  I've tried a variety of scripts, based on suggestions I've found around the interwebs, but nothing seems to work.  The only one I've found that AHK will even load is

```
RWin & n::Send #N
```

But that just ends up sending an uppercase N.  Anyone know how to properly capture <kbd>RWin</kbd> key combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@techturtle, Reading your question still leaves me uncertain as to what you want. Do you want your <kbd>RWin</kbd> to behave like the normal <kbd>Win</kbd> key (Rwin::Lwin) or do you want to create a new set of different combinations with the <kbd>RWin</kbd> key?

Comment: I was trying to get Rwin to behave like Lwin for the custom scripts.  It already worked for the windows default actions.  Amazingly, the `Rwin::Lwin` did the trick.  Don't know why I didn't try that before... I was always trying to remake the combos.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Great to see this is resolved.